# R install my own upload package from github with Timeout:curl_fetch_disk Error

Tags: r, github, package, devtools, install.packages

I can install this package in the local folder by install() I provide the code in the end

however when I upload the package, and try to install from github using:

```
devtools::install_github('yuanqingye/FlighR')
```

I got this message

```
Error in curl::curl_fetch_disk(url, x$path, handle = handle) : 
Timeout was reached: Connection timed out after 10686 milliseconds
```

FYI, I could install other's package from github(no error before)

here is what I install succeed from local's message:

```
install() 
Installing FlightR 
"D:/R/R-33~1.3/bin/x64/R" --no-site-file
"D:/R/R-33~1.3/bin/x64/R" --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save --no-restore --quiet CMD INSTALL  \
"C:/Users/qingye.yuan/Documents/R_Projects/interestingR/FlightR" --library="D:/R/R-3.3.3/library"  \
--install-tests 

* installing *source* package 'FlightR' ...
** R
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
No man pages found in package  'FlightR' 
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (FlightR)
```

Comment: Spelling mistake :) FlightR `devtools::install_github('yuanqingye/FlightR')`

Comment: Oh didn't see your comment. This should be the answer

Comment: thank you both~ I could install my own package, but I am not the first one :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is a typo in your `devtools` command. This works:

```
> devtools::install_github("yuanqingye/FlightR")
Downloading GitHub repo yuanqingye/FlightR@master
✔  checking for file ‘/tmp/RtmplBMbiz/remotes2c88780eef71/yuanqingye-FlightR-135a628/DESCRIPTION’ ...
─  preparing ‘FlightR’:
✔  checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ...

─  checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts
─  checking for empty or unneeded directories
─  building ‘FlightR_1.0.tar.gz’
Installing package into ‘/home/johannes/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
* installing *source* package ‘FlightR’ ...
** R
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
** help
No man pages found in package  ‘FlightR’ 
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (FlightR)
```

Comment: It works now, strange~ thank you very much anyway